# Magento 2 - How to add color picker in admin configuration options?

Tags: magento2

How can I add color picker in Magento admin configuration options?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I sorted it out:

Create system.xml

```
<config ...>
    <system>
        ...
        <section>
            ...
            <group id="my_color_group" ...>
                <field id="my_color_option" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Background Color</label>
                    <comment><![CDATA[Background color]]></comment>
                    <frontend_model>Webspeaks\Color\Block\Color</frontend_model> <!-- Our block for attaching color picker to text box -->
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Create the block file:

```
<?php
namespace Webspeaks\Color\Block;

class Color extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field {

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element) {
        $html = $element->getElementHtml();
        $value = $element->getData('value');

        $html .= '<script type="text/javascript">
            require(["jquery","jquery/colorpicker/js/colorpicker"], function ($) {
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    var $el = $("#' . $element->getHtmlId() . '");
                    $el.css("backgroundColor", "'. $value .'");

                    // Attach the color picker
                    $el.ColorPicker({
                        color: "'. $value .'",
                        onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                            $el.css("backgroundColor", "#" + hex).val("#" + hex);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
            </script>';
        return $html;
    }

}
```

Add JavaScript color picker library:

```
<!-- File: app/code/Webspeaks/Color/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="jquery/colorpicker/css/colorpicker.css"/>
        <link src="jquery/colorpicker/js/colorpicker.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Complete source code: http://www.webspeaks.in/2016/03/add-color-picker-in-magento-2-admin-configuration-options.html

Comment: Not working in magento2.2.1.

Comment: Not working in magento2.2.2

Comment: Working on magento2.2.8

Comment: Not working in magento2.3.3

Comment: Not working in magento2.4

Comment: Not working in magento2.4.1

Answer (score 5):

Follow below step

**Create system.xml at Below Path**

app/code/Emizentech/Newsletter/etc/adminhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">


<system>
    <tab id="emizentechnewsletter" translate="label" sortOrder="700">
        <label>Emizentech Newsletter Pop-up</label>
    </tab>
    <section id="emizentechnewsletter" translate="label" sortOrder="500" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <class>separator-top</class>
        <label>Emizentech Newsletter Configuration</label>
        <tab>emizentechnewsletter</tab>
        <resource>Emizentech_Newsletter::config</resource>


        <group id="txt" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">


            <label>Emizentech</label>


            <field id="colorsample" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="4" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="1">
                <label>Font color for newsletter popup</label>
                <comment><![CDATA[Text color]]></comment>
                <frontend_model>Emizentech\Newsletter\Block\Color</frontend_model> <!-- Our block for attaching color picker to text box -->
            </field>
        </group>


    </section>
</system>

</config>
```

**Create Color.php File at below Path**

```
<?php

namespace Emizentech\Newsletter\Block;
class Fontcolor extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field {

/**
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
 * @param Registry $coreRegistry
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element) {
    $html = $element->getElementHtml();
    $value = $element->getData('value');

    $html .= '<script type="text/javascript">
        require(["jquery","jquery/colorpicker/js/colorpicker"], function ($) {


            $(document).ready(function () {
                var $el = $("#' . $element->getHtmlId() . '");
                $el.css("backgroundColor", "'. $value .'");

                // Attach the color picker
                $el.ColorPicker({
                    color: "'. $value .'",
                    onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                        $el.css("backgroundColor", "#" + hex).val("#" + hex);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        </script>';
    return $html;
}
}
```

**Add color picker CSS library:**

Create **adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml** at Below Path

app/code/Emizentech/Newsletter/view/adminhtml/layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="jquery/colorpicker/css/colorpicker.css"/>
</head>
```

Comment: Not working in magento2.2.1

Answer (score 5):

> **code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/ColorPicker.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field;

class ColorPicker extends Field
{
    /**
     * add color picker in admin configuration fields
     * @param  \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element
     * @return string script
     */
    protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $html = $element->getElementHtml();
        $value = $element->getData('value');

        $html .= '<script type="text/javascript">
            require(["jquery"], function ($) {
                $(document).ready(function (e) {
                    $("#' . $element->getHtmlId() . '").css("background-color","#' . $value . '");
                    $("#' . $element->getHtmlId() . '").colpick({
                        layout:"hex",
                        submit:0,
                        colorScheme:"dark",
                        color: "#' . $value . '",
                        onChange:function(hsb,hex,rgb,el,bySetColor) {
                        $(el).css("background-color","#"+hex);
                        if(!bySetColor) $(el).val(hex);
                    }
                    }).keyup(function(){
                        $(this).colpickSetColor(this.value);
                    });
                });
            });
            </script>';

        return $html;
    }
}
```

> **code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="vendor" translate="label" sortOrder="250" >
            <label>Vendor</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="Color" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Color</label>
            <tab>vendor</tab>
            <group id="design" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Color</label>
                <field id="color" translate="label" sortOrder="20" type="text" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Color</label>
                    <frontend_model>Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\ColorPicker</frontend_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Tested in Magento version 2.2.4 and 2.2.5 ... 2.3.2 ... 2.4.3**

I don't know about all but in the above Magento versions from the admin, if we go to the `Store->Configuration` and then check the `View page source` we can see below js

`adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Dotdigitalgroup_Email/js/node_modules/colpick/colpick.js`

If you open the js you will know it's a color picker js. So why not use the color picker js which is already loading on the page. No need to add any external JS or CSS.

My solution is as below.

Replace `[Vendor]` with your `Namespace` and `[Module]` with your `Modulename`.

**[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/adminhtml/system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="[vendor]" sortOrder="297">
            <label>[Vendor]</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="[vendor]_[module]" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <tab>[vendor]</tab>
            <label>[Your Label]</label>
            <resource>[Vendor]_[Module]::core_config</resource>
            <group id="[your-group-id]" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="250" showInDefault="1">
                <field id="[your-field-id]" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1">
                    <label>Choose Color</label>
                    <frontend_model>[Vendor]\[Module]\Block\ColorPicker</frontend_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

For the color picker, all you need is add a field

```
<field id="[your-field-id]" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1">
     <label>Choose Color</label>
     <frontend_model>[Vendor]\[Module]\Block\ColorPicker</frontend_model>           
</field>
```

Create **[Vendor]/[Module]/Block/ColorPicker.php**

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Block;
 
class ColorPicker extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    array $data = []
    ) 
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
 
    /**
     * add color picker in admin configuration fields
     * @param  \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element
     * @return string script
     */
    protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $html = $element->getElementHtml();
        $value = $element->getData('value');
 
        $html .= '<script type="text/javascript">
            require(["jquery"], function ($) {
                $(document).ready(function (e) {
                    $("#'.$element->getHtmlId().'").css("background-color","#'.$value.'");
                    $("#'.$element->getHtmlId().'").colpick({
                        layout:"hex",
                        submit:0,
                        colorScheme:"dark",
                        color: "#'.$value.'",
                        onChange:function(hsb,hex,rgb,el,bySetColor) {
                        $(el).css("background-color","#"+hex);
                        if(!bySetColor) $(el).val(hex);
                    }
                    }).keyup(function(){
                        $(this).colpickSetColor(this.value);
                    });
                });
            });
            </script>';
 
        return $html;
    }
}
```

That's it. It solved my problem. So if that js is loading on the page It should definitely work. It is working for me.

Answer (score 2):

In 2022, you can just return `<input type="color">` in `Block/Color.php`

```
protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
{
    return '<input type="color" id="' . 
        $element->getHtmlId() .
        '" name="' . 
        $element->getName() . 
        '" value="' . 
        $element->getEscapedValue() . 
        '"/>';
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/color