# Magento 2.2.1- How to fix ColorPicker issue in admin configuration?

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.2

I have used custom color picker in my extension and I remove it but got this error.

[image]

I checked following questions but not working anymore in `Magento 2.2.1`.

[Magento 2.1.1 - How to add color picker in admin configuration options?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137605/magento-2-1-1-how-to-add-color-picker-in-admin-configuration-options/137629)

[Magento 2 - How to add color picker in admin configuration options?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103316/magento-2-how-to-add-color-picker-in-admin-configuration-options?noredirect=1&lq=1)[enter link description here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103316/magento-2-how-to-add-color-picker-in-admin-configuration-options?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: did you run `static:content` and update your PUB folder? Because it seems like its calling from pub folder or may be cache

Comment: yes I already did. js is loading but issue is "Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function ($) {" ...color picker

Answer (score 0):

Your issue can be not shim jquery.

I also added ColorPicker to Magento Admin.

I think this can be resolved for you.

I used this ColorPicker: https://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/

**Step 1**: Add JS, add CSS file

- In **requirejs-config.js**:

```
var config = {
    "shim": {
        "Package_Module::color_picker/colorpicker": ["jquery"]
    }
};
```

- In **default.xml**:

**Step 2**: Add JS to block

**Package_Module/Block/ColorPicker.php**

```
namespace Package\Module\Block;

class ColorPicker extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element) {
        $html = $element->getElementHtml();
        $value = $element->getData('value');

        $html .= '
            
            require(["jquery"], function ($) {
                require(["Package_Module/color_picker/colorpicker"], function() {
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        var $el = $("#' . $element->getHtmlId() . '");
                        $el.css("background-color", "'. $value .'");

                        // Attach the color picker
                        $el.ColorPicker({
                            color: "'. $value .'",
                            onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                                $el.css("backgroundColor", "#" + hex).val("#" + hex);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
            ';
        return $html;
    }
}
```

**Step 3**: Call for field config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="colorpicker" translate="label" sortOrder="100">
            <label>ColorPicker</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="package_colorpicker" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Theme Options</label>
            <tab>colorpicker</tab>
            <resource>Package_Module::config_theme_options</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <field id="main_color" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="15" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Main Color</label>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Good Luck!

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense, what inside "In default.xml:"?

Answer (score -1):

```
<preference for="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart" type="WebdesignStudenten\TablePricing\CustomerData\Cart" />

<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace WebdesignStudenten\TablePricing\CustomerData;

/**
 * Cart source
 */
class Cart extends \Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart
{

    /**
     * Get array of last added items
     *
     * @return \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item[]
     */
    protected function getRecentItems()
    {

        $items = [];
        if (!$this->getSummaryCount()) {
            return $items;
        }

        foreach (array_reverse($this->getAllQuoteItems()) as $item) {

            /* @var $item \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item */
            if (!$item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility()) {
                $product =  $item->getOptionByCode('product_type') !== null
                    ? $item->getOptionByCode('product_type')->getProduct()
                    : $item->getProduct();

                $products = $this->catalogUrl->getRewriteByProductStore([$product->getId() => $item->getStoreId()]);
                if (!isset($products[$product->getId()])) {

                    if ($product->getId()){             
                        $items[] = $this->itemPoolInterface->getItemData($item); // "not visible individually" product having id 4 added into items array
                    }
                    continue;
                }
                $urlDataObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($products[$product->getId()]);
                $item->getProduct()->setUrlDataObject($urlDataObject);
            }
            $items[] = $this->itemPoolInterface->getItemData($item);
        }
        return $items;
    }
}
```